# Ember syntax errors

Tags: ember.js

I am learning ember.js with a tutorial that is built in to their [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/getting-started/quick-start/). Having installed it successfully, I followed the steps and created a new application with `ember new ember-quickstart`, generated a template and defined a route.  However, the data that I've included in the route model is not being rendered (there appears to be a parsing error due to an unexpected token default), but I have no idea what it might be referring to.  I have pasted the code exactly as it appears.  Any suggestions as to what might be causing the error?

```
SyntaxError: ember-quickstart/routes/scientists.js: Unexpected token (3:2)
```

[image]

#### routes/scientists.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

  default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return['Marie Curie', 'Albert Einstein', 'Andrei Sakharov']
  }
});
```

#### templates/scientists.hbs

```
<h2>List of Scientists</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each model as |scientist|}}
  <li>{{scientist}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

#### templates/application.hbs

```
<h2 id="title">Welcome To Ember</h2>

{{outlet}}
```

#### app/router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('scientists');
});

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default Ember.Route.extend({
```

should be:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
```